# C - error: request for member ‘---’ in something not a structure or union

Tags: c, pointers, stack

This question has been asked before, but from what I have seen it's all people that are misusing `'a.b'` to get pointer values. I AM using `'a->b'` but it is still throwing this error.
Here's my code, it's meant to be a dynamic stack:

Header file:

```
typedef struct etCel{
    element *ele;
    struct cel *suiv;   
} cel;

typedef cel* pile;

pile init_pile();
int affiche_pile(pile *p);
```

.c file:

```
pile init_pile(pile *p){
    return NULL;
}
int affiche_pile(pile *p){
    printf("Valeurs de la pile:\n");
    while(p!=NULL){
        affiche_element(p->ele);
        printf("\n");
        p=*(p->suiv);
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: You've `typedef` pile as a pointer to a cel, then you're passing a `pile` pointer into the function, this is a pointer to a pointer to a cel.

Comment: [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please

Comment: `pile` is typedef'ed as pointer type to `etCel/cel` but `pile*` means pointer to another pointer (double indirection). Hence you are getting the error.

Comment: This question should be saved to prove that **hide pointers with `typedef` is The Evil**

Comment: @Danh This seems like an MCVE to me...

Comment: @MDXF Not compilable

Comment: @Danh the 'C' stands for 'Complete'. But even so, you have a point.

Comment: @MDXF __Ensure that the example actually reproduces the problem!__ Shouldn't it mean compilable

Comment: @Danh I'm just stating what the definition of an MCVE is. Whether or not it *should* mean compilable, it *does* mean complete.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
typedef cel* pile;
```

and

```
int affiche_pile(pile *p){
```

This leads to believe that `p` is now a pointer to a pointer. Expand the declarations and you get

```
cel* *p;
```

So either you change the function signature to `int affiche_pile(pile p)` or `typedef cel pile`

Answer (score 1):

`pile *p` is double pointer so you change your code something like this:

```
affiche_element((*p)->ele);
```

Change at other places too.